# given n segments on the plane pairwise intersecting and distincty so, can you draw another segment intersecting the rest?

Tags: geometry

Just to rephrase in case the question isn't clear:
There are n segments on the 2d plane  so that every two segments intersects and no two intersection points are alike (there are no intersection points where 3 lines pass). Can another segment intersecting the rest be drawn (and so the new intersections are also distinct)?

Drawing this question on the board, intuitively the answer is "yes", but I can't put the finger on any explanations as to why. I'll note that if the points aren't distinct the answer is no, as you can make an example with a triangle and any line from one of the vertices to a side.

many thanks in advance

Comment: If you select a segment, a point on it which isn't a point of intersection of this segment with another one, and rotate your segment by sufficiently small angle $\alpha$, wouldn't you get the answer?

Comment: Thanks, that works.
I'll note for future googlers that this works only if you also require that the endpoints are distinct from the intersections otherwise a triangle is a counter-example.

Much thanks!